# Known JSON file looks different in each browser

Tags: json, xml, google-chrome, microsoft-edge

It's not a programming question, but it will be interesting for some developers.

Today I came across a question where user were asking about parsing Json data in C#. Nothing new, but he gave a link with Json file:

[<s>http://sapi.confirmtkt.com/api/platform/hotel/gethotels?city=Bangalore&checkinDate=08-01-2016&checkoutDate=09-01-2016&adults=2&rooms=1&children=0&childrenages=</s>](http://sapi.confirmtkt.com/api/platform/hotel/gethotels?city=Bangalore&checkinDate=08-01-2016&checkoutDate=09-01-2016&adults=2&rooms=1&children=0&childrenages=)

**The page is not available anymore!**.

If you browse the above link in Google Chrome you can notice that the file will be shown as XML. Then I checked the url in Edge and it showed me a Json file.

**Google Chrome**

[image]

**Edge**

[image]

I'm a bit confused. Why Google Chrome shows Json file as XML?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because Chrome is sending different data in the `Accept` HTTP header:

**Chrome's request:**

```
GET http://sapi.confirmtkt.com/api/platform/hotel/gethotels?city=Bangalore&checkinDate=08-01-2016&checkoutDate=09-01-2016&adults=2&rooms=1&children=0&childrenages= HTTP/1.1
Host: sapi.confirmtkt.com
Connection: keep-alive
Cache-Control: max-age=0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/48.0.2564.48 Safari/537.36
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, sdch
Accept-Language: es,en;q=0.8
```

**Edge's request:**

```
GET http://sapi.confirmtkt.com/api/platform/hotel/gethotels?city=Bangalore&checkinDate=08-01-2016&checkoutDate=09-01-2016&adults=2&rooms=1&children=0&childrenages= HTTP/1.1
Accept: text/html, application/xhtml+xml, image/jxr, */*
Accept-Language: es-CL,es;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.5,en;q=0.3
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/46.0.2486.0 Safari/537.36 Edge/13.10586
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Host: sapi.confirmtkt.com
Connection: Keep-Alive
```

You can see how Chrome is accepting `application/xml;q=0.9` in the Accept header. So, I fired up Fiddler and intercepted the GET request, deleted that part of the accept header and now the server replies back with json rather than XML.

[image: Chrome showing JSON]

*TL;DR:* The server was giving back two different responses for the same URL because of the `Accept` header.

Comment: That's it. Thanks for the explanation.